# Change the status of a item in a List if thay already is in the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, power-automate, microsoft-lists

I have a list in sharepoint that we fill in the exceptions for a specific case. So in that list I have the status "Under review", "Approved", "Rejected".

To change this status I have the following flow: If the data I put in the "CNPJ" column, when creating a new item in this list, it is already in the list twice, the status is "Reject", if it is the first or second time, the status is "Approved"

Guys, could you help create this flow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a condensed version of the steps I would follow:

1. Start by clicking on `Create` in the Power Automate Dashboard to initiate a new flow.
2. Choose the flow template labeled `When an item is created`.
3. Connect to the SharePoint site and select the list where you want to apply the flow.
4. Add a new action to the flow. Search for `Get items` and select the `SharePoint - Get items` action.
5. Configure the `Get items` action to retrieve items from the same list, filtering by the `CNPJ` column equal to the value provided in the current item being created.
6. Add a `Condition` action to check the number of items returned from the previous step.
7. In the `Condition` action, specify the condition as `Count of items is greater than 2.`
8. If the condition is true, add an action to update the status column to `Rejected` for the current item.
9. If the condition is false, add an action to update the status column to `Approved` for the current item.
10. Save and test the flow.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it returned as a Error. See in the answer below

Comment: Hi,
I tried but, the field CNPJ return a error. The expression inside the field "CNPJ" is not valid. It is a single line text. and the format is "xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx" when the "x" is numbers

Comment: You need to determine the method to extract the value in the given expression using code. It is achievable; you just need to conduct further research. Additionally, please consider reviewing the following link when you have the opportunity: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar.